# Jquery is adding prevObject: to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to sum all floats in an array

when I do this in the chrome console

```
$("tr.project_hours").find("td.number").map(function(i,v)
{return parseFloat($(v).attr("data-time"))
})
```

I get

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is what I want

But, in my code I have more $("tr.project_hours")  and I want to sum them separately. 
So, I do

```
$("tr.project_hours").each(function(){
    row = $(this).find('td.total')
    row.html(sumInputsIn($(this).find("td.number").map(function(i,v){
     return parseFloat($(v).attr("data-time"))})));
    })
```

('td.total') is the column where the result should be displayed. The problem is that the last code returns this in the console

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[7], context: <tr>]
```

So the result is the notorious NaN.

Why do I get the prevObject in my array? And how can I refactor to get rid of it?

Comment: In other words, show us a sample of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should carry out the expected result:

```
$("tr.project_hours").each(function(index, element) {
    var row = $(this).find('td.total');
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find("td.number").each(function (index, element) {
        total += parseFloat($(v).attr("data-time"));
    });
    row.html(total);
});
```

[jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) performs `for (item in array)` which apparently does not filter by `hasOwnProperty()` if you are getting those keys. In this case you need to write the logic yourself I guess.

Comment: see steveukx's answer for a much better solution to jQuery adding these props

Answer (score 45):

The return type of calling `map` on a jQuery collection is another jQuery collection. If you want to access just the results of the function used in the map, you need to use `.toArray()` to return the underlying array instead:

```
var numbersArray = $("tr.project_hours").find("td.number").map(function(i,v)
  {return parseFloat($(v).attr("data-time"))
}).toArray();
```

Comment: This makes a long array of all the tr.project_hours table rows. I need to separate them

Comment: I see, this answer is more aimed at why you are seeing `prevObject` in the result of using `jQuery.fn.map`.

Comment: Love :), you made my day!

Comment: more than 3 years working with jQuery and only just found this! This seriously made my day!

Comment: "JS object to Array"; For the Google algorithm, that seems to be unable to connect this answer to exactly that search query, only showing it when you search for "prevObject".