# Can this jQuery code with .map() and .toArray() be simplfied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

Can this jQuery code be simplified?

```
var myArray = $(this).parents('.items').find('> a').map(function(){
  return this.innerText
}).toArray();
```

Here I use `.map(function(){return this.innerText})` to return the array with prevObject.

That's why I additionally use `.toArray()` as per [Jquery is adding prevObject: to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193469/jquery-is-adding-prevobject-to-array).

Is it possible to simplify this code? Thank you.

Comment: Not really. Each call there is required. You could use an arrow function and `get()` instead of `toArray()` to shorten the number of characters, and if there's only ever one parent `.items` element then you could use `closest()` instead of `parents()`, but that's about it.

Comment: You can remove the 'return' if you omit the curly brackets

Comment: Depends: what are you actually trying to do? E.g. why is this code finding a sibling through a parent, instead of doing this directly on the parent? What do you need that innerText for? Etc. Because sometimes a "simplificaiton" consists of "throw this away, and write different code somewhere else", which might be the case here, or might not be.